# using lodash _find to return true or false

Tags: angularjs, find, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash function to find if it satisfies the if statement. When the code has run the code which 'return false', it stills continue execute the _find function and did not return the result (boolean value) in the scope.onToggle.

```
 $scope.onToggle = function(disposition) {
      if (requiredFieldsEntered()===false){
         // if return value from the function is false, alert user
       } 
  }

 function requiredFieldsEntered(){
    var res = _.find($rootScope.CustomFields, 
      function(field){

       if(field.enabled && field.required){
         if(field.table_name === 'session'){
           if(!$scope.session.external_id){
               console.log(field.column_name);
               return false;
           }
           else if (field.table_name === "session_extension"){
              if(!$scope.session.extension|| ($scope.session.extension && !$scope.session.extension[field.column_name])){
                 console.log(field.column_name);
                 return false;
           }
        }
      } 
    }});

    if (res) return false;
    else return true;
  }
```

Comment: For starters, you are missing the closing curly bracket for your line `if(field.enabled && field.required){`. See if fixing that solves the problem before we dig into whether the `requiredFieldsEntered()` function is really written to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I  forget the closing curly bracket while typing the question. Maybe I could use for loop instead of lodash method. I'll try

Comment: As written the `requiredFieldsEntered()` function will always execute the `else` clause and return `true`. The lodash `_.find` will always return `undefined` because there is never a case where the predicate function returns anything truthy.

Answer (score 0):

First let's stop and consider what `_.find` actually does. It loops over an array and returns the first element of the array that matches the condition.

```
_.find([1, 2, 3, 4], function(num) { return num % 2 === 0 });
// returns 2
```

In the case of your `_.find` function, then, you'll either get back one of the fields from `$rootScope.CustomFields` or `undefined` if none of the fields returns a truthy value from `function(field)…`.

Here is where you have your problem. The anonymous function `function(field)…` only ever returns false. You need to return true if you find an error, or else return false otherwise.

Since your `requiredFieldsEntered()` function is ultimately trying to return either `true` or `false`, you can decide which of those to return based on whether or not your `_.find` function returns some object or `undefined`.

Something like this:

```
$scope.onToggle = function(disposition) {
  if (requiredFieldsEntered()===false){
    // if return value from the function is false, alert user
  }
}

function requiredFieldsEntered(){
  const fieldWithErrors = _.find($rootScope.CustomFields,
    function(field){
      let result = true;
      if(field.enabled && field.required){
        if(field.table_name === 'session'){
          if(!$scope.session.external_id){
            console.log(field.column_name);
            result = false;
          } else if (field.table_name === "session_extension"){
            if(!$scope.session.extension|| ($scope.session.extension && !$scope.session.extension[field.column_name])){
              console.log(field.column_name);
              result = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    });

  if (fieldWithErrors) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

---

Quick note that a shorter but somewhat less-readable version at the end may replace this bit:

```
…
  if (fieldWithErrors) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

With:

```
…
return !!!fieldWithErrors;
```

The first two exclamation points would be typecasting the result of your find function to either `true` if it comes up with something or `false` if it returns `undefined`, and then the third exclamation point would invert that boolean to match your current scheme of returning `false` if there are errors.

(Or you could change your function name to `errorsArePresent` and return `true` – `!!fieldWithErrors`).